# Xamarin.Android: IllegalArgumentException while loading supprt.v7.toolbar

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, android-support-library

I am getting an IllegalArgumentException while loading supprt.v7.toolbar after editing one of xaml files.

**Here is what the compiler is telling me**

```
Creating class loader with 0 projects

Creating LibraryClassLoader in shadow copy path C:\Users\konno\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidDesignerJars180644833948983183

Trying to load class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

mono.android.DesignerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:46)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:187)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:239)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:704)
at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column indices (start + span) mustn't exceed the column count. 
at android.widget.GridLayout.handleInvalidParams(GridLayout.java:823)
at android.widget.GridLayout.checkLayoutParams(GridLayout.java:837)
at android.widget.GridLayout.checkLayoutParams(GridLayout.java:853)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4462)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4295)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4267)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:862)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:233)
... 4 more
```

The only thing that I did to the toolbar was change what row it is on. Then after re-opening it in the designer, I got the error above. I tried removing the line of code that I had added to the toolbar, but the error remained.

**XAML Code for Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="6">
<!--This is for the Toolbar Only-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/RestaurantTotalToolbar"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<!--This is for the Toolbar Only-->
<!--What is the Ticket Total? -->
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/questTicketTotal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/questTicketTextView"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_rowWeight="10" />
    <EditText
        android:hint="$0.00"
        android:id="@+id/ticketTotal"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:translationY="-60dp"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLines="1" />
<!--What is the name of the Restaurant? -->
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/questRestaurantName"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/restaurantNameTextView"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_rowWeight="10"
        android:translationY="-35dp" />
    <EditText
        android:hint="Restaurant Name"
        android:id="@+id/restaurantName"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:translationY="-100dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1" />
    <Button
        android:text="@string/nextButton"
        android:id="@+id/calcButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toolbar isn't causing the problem. 'android:layout_columnSpan="3"' is causing the problem, because the button is set in column 2, and I was trying to set its span to 3, which it can't do.

**This change to the button code fixes the issue**

```
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_columnSpan="3"
```